# OSX-formatted USB drive giving strange partition message when I attempt to eject it. "Boot OSX" hidden partition?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, usb, disk-utility, partition

I have a USB3 drive with 128GB of storage.  It has been working normally up until this evening, when I tried to right click > eject the drive.  I received the following message:

```
“Mymusic” is a partition on a disk that has 2 partitions. Do you want to eject “Mymusic” only, or both partitions?
```

When I open Disk Utility, it only shows the one single partition listed under the drive.  I ran First Aid on the drive itself, and it reported no problems.  However, when I tried running First Aid on the partition, it failed because it could not eject the drive.

If I click on the drive in the list, and click Partition, it shows a pie chart and 100% of the drive is shown in blue, as one big partition taking up 100% of the disk.  The only thing that looks weird is maybe "Child Count: 3".

Lastly, and perhaps most importantly, when I finally clicked "Close All [volumes]", I got this message:

```
The disk "Boot OSX" wasn't ejected because one or more programs may be using it.
```

Hitting "retry" continues to fail.

The disk has been formatted several times, and the most recent format was about a week ago.  It has only ever had one partition (at least, that I added myself; and no one else has physical access to it).  I certainly never added a partition named "Boot OSX".  Maybe some malware or something? But I don't pirate software and am privy to attachments, security, etc.

Here are a couple of screenshots, in case they help:

[image: Disk Utility 1]
[image: Disk Utility 2]

I'm not sure how this can happen.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This EFI partition is discussed at :
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4326715?start=0&tstart=0
The opinion there is that it is created by (some versions of) Time Machine.
Disk Utility hides it by default, but see
https://www.mede8erforum.com/index.php?topic=14019.0
for how to show it and remove it.